# Allowing Filtering in DropDown while forcing value in ComboBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am trying to get a combobox dropdown that allows users to type into the combobox to filter the dropdown but enforces that the user must select one of the available options and can not just enter whatever they want. I have the code below and the

```
comboBoxProperties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
```

line is supposed to only let users select one of the available options but I am still able to type whatever I want and hit tab and the field just stays whatever I typed.

```
USStateCollection states = new USStateCollection();
    states.LoadAll();
    states.Filter = states.AsQueryable().OrderBy(d => d.StateName);
    settings.Columns.Add(c =>
    {
        c.Caption = "State";
        c.FieldName = "State";
        c.Width = Unit.Percentage(10);
        c.Settings.FilterMode = ColumnFilterMode.Value;
        c.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = c.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = states;
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "StateName";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "StateAbbrev";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(System.String);
        comboBoxProperties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBoxProperties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
    });
```

Comment: So, do you want to prevent from entering a filter?

Comment: No I want to be able to type a filter but be forced to select one of the entries in the dropdown and not just enter my own custom text.